# Error on setting Hikari MetricRegistry

Tags: playframework-2.0, hikaricp

I am trying to use MetricRegistry for Hikary in a Play! application in Java as explained on Hikari's [GitHub page](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Dropwizard-Metrics). This is basically what I did:

```
 HikariDataSource dataSource = ((HikariDataSource) db.dataSource());
 dataSource.setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
```

But Hikari is complaining because the MetricRegistry shouldn't be set after construction. This is the error message I am getting:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The configuration of the pool is
>   sealed once started.  Use HikariConfigMXBean for runti me changes.

Is there a better way to set this property, for example, by setting up the pool in the application config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @PostConstruct for this purpose:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    private final MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public DataSourceConfiguration(final MetricRegistry metricRegistry, final DataSource dataSource) {
        this.metricRegistry = metricRegistry;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setUpHikariWithMetrics() {
        if (dataSource instanceof HikariDataSource) {
            ((HikariDataSource) dataSource).setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
        }
    }
}
```